# Object passing data to an angular $resource missing some fields, but not others

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, object, angular-resource

I'm passing data into a `$resource` from an object. However, before sending the object to the resource I'm sending it away to be processed to `geocode` it.

The geocode function alters the **`$scope.formData`** to add `lat` and `lng` data to it.

I'm getting these all ok. However, when I create the `$resource` the lat and lng properties are missing, which is super odd.

Here is the code:

```
$scope.ok = function (){
    $scope.geocode($scope.formData);
    var data = $scope.formData;
    /* the lat and lng data are in the data object*/
    console.log(data);

        var appointment = new Appointment(data);
                    /* the lat and lng are missing from this resource object*/
                    console.log(appointment);
}
```

Appointment is defined as a factory:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.factory('Appointment', function($resource){
    return $resource('/api/admin/:id', { id: "@_id" }, {
         query: {method:'GET', isArray:true}, 
         update: { method:'PUT' }
    });

})
```

created an external factory for the geocoder to be able to call it from any controller:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.factory('geocoder', ['$http','$state', function($http, $state){

var geocoder ={};

geocoder.geocode = function (formData){
    var myformData = {};
    var address = formData.address_1+', '+formData.city+', '+formData.postcode;

                var key = 'mykey';

                $http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+address+'&key='+key).
                  success(function(results, status, headers, config) {
                    var results = results.results[0];
                    formData.lat = results.geometry.location.lat;
                    formData.lng = results.geometry.location.lng;
                        myformData = formData;
                    return myformData;          

                     // this callback will be called asynchronously
                    // when the response is available
                  }).
                  error(function(results, status, headers, config) {
                    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                    // or server returns response with an error status.
                  });   
}


return geocoder;

}])
```

can anyone explain this?

Comment: where is `Appointment` defined?

Comment: hey Daniel - just added this above - apologies

Comment: where's the geocode completion callback? Sounds like you are trying to save outside of that callback...which is asynchronous. Not enough code shown

Comment: hi charlietfl - sorry - I'm a noob - I've changed this and have turned the geocoder into a factor and added the code above. The problem I'm still having is that I can't access the data inside the Resource object

Comment: @Mobaz try to return promise from your `geocode` function and handle success result inside of your controller. Here is an example: http://jsbin.com/boxeratato/19/edit?html,js,console,output